# Render Animation Not Working Anymore

Tags: rendering, video

I'm using blender for some basic video editing (no 3D modeling involved, nothing fancier than cutting the beginning and ending off a video and adding some images over parts of it), and edited and rendered two videos with no problems. When I finished editing my third video (same length as the previous two, same source file types, same settings, same everything), I clicked Render Animation as usual but the render field that pops up remained empty, and the file is never rendered to the selected output folder (or any other folder). I let it sit for a while with no change, so I closed out and tried again. Then closed Blender completely and tried again, to no avail. I went back and tried rendering a previous video, and it rendered fine (again), but this one I've just done will not render. I have no idea what's going on. Help?

Comment: Have you accidentally change the Frame range in the Output Properties setting (or the Timeline)?

Comment: pls upload blend file - could be several reasons. Unfortunately you didn't show us any of your settings.